# Type Date initial value

Tags: anylogic

I try to set the initial value of Variable (Type: Date) to "2023-01-04 01:05:30.0".
I tried every combination, but I always get an error that the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The better (and non-deprecated) approach would be to use `LocalDate` and turn it into a `Date`:

```
LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.JULY, 29, 19, 30, 40).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())
```

Read up on LocalDate and LocalDateTime as they are extremely useful for date manipulations. Only convert back to `Date` when all is computed and you need it for the model. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-to-localdate-and-localdatetime